# A conjectured identity with Hölder conjugate exponents: if $|x|^p+|y|^p=1$, then $|x+y|^{p^*}+|x-y|^{p^*}=2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $1\leq p<\infty$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x|^p+|y|^p=1$. If $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p^*}=1$, prove that $|x+y|^{p^*}+|x-y|^{p^*}=2$.

Actually I do not know if this is true. I think so, but I do not know how to prove.

Comment: Remark : I don't know how to solve the problem, but this problem has a symmetry : If you write $1/p + 1/q = 1$, write the first statement as $(|x|^p + |y|^p)^{1/p} = 1$ and the second as $(|(x+y)/2|^q + |(x-y)/2|^q)^{1/q} = 1$. Then the question is symmetric in $p$ and $q$ via the map $(x,y) \mapsto ( (x+y)/2, (x-y)/2)$ (with inverse map the same map, i.e. this map is an involution of $\mathbb R^2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the answer is simple since $p=3,x=(1/3)^{1/3},y=(2/3)^{1/3}$. Then $p^*=3/2$ and 
$$p=(|x+y|^{p^*}+|x-y|^{p^*})/2=\frac{1}{2}((2^{1/3}+1)^{3/2}+(2^{1/3}-1)^{3/2})(1/3)^{1/2}$$
When squaring we get $$p^2=\frac{1}{12}(4+6\cdot 2^{1/3}+2(2^{2/3}-1)^{3/2})$$
We prove that this is not $1$, since we prove $3\cdot 2^{1/3}+ (2^{2/3}-1)^{3/2} \not = 4$, move to right hand side and squaring we get $(4-3\cdot 2^{1/3})^2\not = (2^{2/3}-1)^{3}$. The integral part on left is $16$ and on right is $3$.

PS: I think what you need may be the [Clarkson's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkson's_inequalities). Namely $$\left|\frac{x+y}{2}\right|^{p^*/p}+\left|\frac{x-y}{2}\right|^{p^*/p}\le \left(\frac{1}{2} |x|^p+\frac{1}{2}|y|^p\right)^{p^*/p}$$
when $1<p<2$.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. I think that $p^2$ is not what you said. By my calculations, $p^2=\frac{1}{12}(6+6\cdot 2^{2/3}+2(2^{2/3}-1)^{3/2})$...

Comment: @user102058 $((2^{1/3}+1)^{3/2}+(2^{1/3}-1)^{3/2})^2=(2^{1/3}+1)^3+(2^{1/3}-1)^3+\ldots$ $=\textrm{first term and third term in expansion}+\ldots=4+\ldots$, why do you think it is $6$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake. You're right. Thank you!

Comment: That's Okay, hope that you will find a true theorem!